# Closure-compiler: adding prefix to obfuscated variables

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler, prefix

My goal is adding prefix that will be prepended to all obfuscate variables.
for example:
instead of obfuscating `myVar` into `x`, it will use the prefix `$pre` so the result will be something like: `$prex`

I'm using closure-compiler. Following [Closure-compiler wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options), I've used `rename_variable_prefix` with no success unfortunately.

Code example:

```
const ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').jsCompiler;

console.log(ClosureCompiler.CONTRIB_PATH); // absolute path to the contrib folder which contains externs

const closureCompiler = new ClosureCompiler({
  compilation_level: 'ADVANCED',
  rename_variable_prefix: '$pre'
});

const compilerProcess = closureCompiler.run([{
 path: 'file-one.js',
 src: 'function add(node){
          let test = window["test"];
          if (node.hzix == test)return 1;
       }
       add(window["node"]);
       window.add = add;',
 sourceMap: null // optional input source map
}], (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) => {
  //compilation complete
});
```

The result code is:

```
  {\n"version":3,\n"file":"compiled.js",\n"lineCount":1,\n"mappings":"AAAiGA,MAAAC,IAAA,CAAjGA,QAAY,CAACC,CAAD,CAAM,CAA2B,GAAIA,CAAAC,EAAJ,EAAfH,MAAAI,KAAe,CAAsB,MAAO,EAAxD;",\n"sources":["file-one.js"],\n"names":["window","add","node","hzix","test"]\n}\n',
src: 'window.add=function(a){if(a.a==window.test)return 1};
```

The result did not include the prefix '$pre'. What am i missing?

Comment: I couldn't make it work either, not with the Java, nor with the JS compilers... Maybe try going back a few versions?

Comment: Actually, I rolled back to 20171203 and couldn't make it work.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Although the docs about rename_variable_prefix flag says: "Specifies a prefix that will be prepended to all variables.". The documentation in source code are saying: "Specifies a prefix for all globals". so this flag adds prefixes, but just for global variables. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/66a852612e04e26da77206b80e10db3c92c30489/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L636

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, I got this to work in the Java closure compiler via the compiler option, renamePrefix. e.g.

```
m_options.renamePrefix = "$pre";
```

Where m_options is the CompilerOptions passed to e.g. compileModules:

```
m_compiler.compileModules(m_externals, m_modules, m_options);
```

My issue was that I had a collision with another global obfuscated variable from a 3rd party module, both using the global namespace. The result was a subtle and therefore dangerous bug that only occurred in minified code.

e.g. The minifier generates global symbols aa, ab, ga etc which could easily collide with the same symbols from another minified package - so you can see the inspiration for modules.

I think you would always want to at least prefix minified globals, otherwise this could be a ticking time bomb if you're also loading 3rd party libs.